# How to resolve inconsistent Appium Desktop versions and update messages?

Tags: appium

If I go to `appium.io` I find a download link at `github.com/appium/appium-desktop` for stable 1.13.0 at https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/

There also exists a `github.com/appium/appium` repository at https://github.com/appium/appium/releases with current stable 1.14.1

On my Mac, I am running `Version 1.14.0 (1.14.0.20190705.4)` according to the `Appium→About Appium` menu, the main window shows the button `Start Server v1.14.0`, and starting a server shows `Welcome to Appium v1.14.0` in the log, but selecting `Check For Updates` in the menu tells me that `Appium Desktop v1.13.0 is available` from May 5, which includes an update to Appium version 1.13.0.

How do I resolve these differing version numbers and the apparent downgrade?

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows. :)

Comment: Did you try posting this as a GitHub issue on one of the appium repositories? This seems like a question that only the maintainers will really be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion :

- If you are able to work as expected with installed Appium stable version then just ignore this version update/upgrade messages
- Another option would be to uncheck/de-select check for updates for Appium desktop application